# Kitchen ceiling leaking when using dishwasher

Tags: plumbing-fixture

We have a leak on the kitchen ceiling when we used the dishwasher or the hot water on the kitchen sink.

We have removed the cabinet and have the plumber look at it and found out that there is a point in a joint in the pipe where the water is coming from. He said there was no relation between the pipe above and the hot water BUT it is happening.

He applied the sealing that it is used to seal the outside parts of boats, it didn't work! He then applied a silicone, cement ... mixed, it worked for a week or so, and now it is leaking again.

The next step for him is to open the ceiling more (we already have about 2x2 hole) and cut the pipe and replace it.

I am worried that it would be some kind of pressure and the change in pipe wouldn't stop the leak after expending time and money.

Any advice please? We have had this problem for a long time and now the kitchen ceiling has been opened for 2 months.

Comment: I would get a real plumber.  Those so called fixes are only for emergency use(need water for a fire type).  Unknown if plumbers are licensed, but reporting them to someplace would be decent warning for other people.

Comment: Sealants, silicones, cements, etc., applied to the outside of a leaking pipe, is *never* a permanent fix and is rarely effective...

Comment: Besides the competence of the "plumber" I'm curious why it only leaks when you run the hot water.

Answer (score 5):

Get a competent plumber.

There’s no reason in the world that a leak can’t be fixed right the first time.

(And if possible, retract the payment to the first one.)

Comment: About a ten minute job for a real plumber, half of that is turning off the shut off valve.